# how to fix my filter table under nav bar and head

Tags: html, css, filter

I'm using Weebly to setup my website, I have a problem with my filter/search table, which override my nav bar and banner, wondering is it occurs from default setting.

The table even block my nav bar to go other pages please see [https://www.winlycarservises.com/car-list.html][1], my nav original should be in black you may see from my home page here [https://www.winlycarservises.com/][2]

```css
.tg {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.tg td {
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  word-break: normal;
}

.tg th {
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  word-break: normal;
}

.tg .tg-7xvo {
  background-color: #FFF;
  border-color: inherit;
  color: #333;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: bottom
}

.tg .tg-zjde {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-color: inherit;
  color: #333;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: bottom
}

.tg .tg-z8sk {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-color: inherit;
  color: #333;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: bottom
}

.tg .tg-1oy4 {
  background-color: #303498;
  border-color: inherit;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif !important;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: bottom
}

.tg .tg-go7a {
  background-color: #303498;
  border-color: #ffffff;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: bottom
}

.tg .tg-bsao {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-color: inherit;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: bottom
}

.tg .tg-6nlf {
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
  border-color: inherit;
  color: #333;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: bottom
}

.tg .tg-sd5x {
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
  border-color: inherit;
  color: #333;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: bottom
}

.tg .tg-u6p5 {
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
  border-color: inherit;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: bottom
}

.tg .tg-faa2 {
  background-color: #FFF;
  border-color: inherit;
  color: #333;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: bottom
}

.tg .tg-4hoz {
  background-color: #E9E9E9;
  border-color: inherit;
  color: #333;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: bottom
}

.tg .tg-ogn9 {
  background-color: #E9E9E9;
  border-color: inherit;
  color: #333;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: bottom
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <input id="filterTable-input" data-type="search" placeholder="Search For Cars...">
</form>



<table data-role="table" data-mode="columntoggle" class="tg" id="tg-8fwH3" data-filter="true" data-input="#filterTable-input">


  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="tg-1oy4">Make<br>車廠</th>
      <th class="tg-1oy4">Model<br>型號</th>
      <th class="tg-1oy4">Image<br>圖片</th>
      <th class="tg-1oy4">Mfg. Year<br>年份</th>
      <th class="tg-1oy4">Transmission<br>傳動</th>
      <th class="tg-1oy4">Fuel Type<br>燃油類型</th>
      <th class="tg-1oy4">Engine Size<br>容積</th>
      <th class="tg-1oy4">Door<br>車門</th>
      <th class="tg-1oy4">Seats<br>座位</th>
      <th class="tg-1oy4">Body Color<br>顏色</th>
      <th class="tg-1oy4">Ownership(s)<br>手數</th>
      <th class="tg-go7a">Mileage<br>里數</th>
      <th class="tg-go7a">Gov. Licence<br>牌費</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="tg-z8sk">Toyota</td>
      <td class="tg-z8sk"><a href="https://www.winlycarservises.com/2001-toyota-bb-open-desk-15-yl.html" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Bb Opendeck</a></td>
      <td class="tg-zjde"><img src="https://www.winlycarservises.com/uploads/8/9/5/6/89560713/20220307-113138-mh1646985388801-1_orig.jpg" alt=" 2001 Toyota bb Open desk 1.5" width="200" height="150"></td>
      <td class="tg-zjde">2001</td>
      <td class="tg-zjde">AT</td>
      <td class="tg-zjde">汽油</td>
      <td class="tg-zjde">1500</td>
      <td class="tg-zjde">3</td>
      <td class="tg-zjde">5</td>
      <td class="tg-zjde">黃</td>
      <td class="tg-zjde">未出牌</td>
      <td class="tg-bsao">/</td>
      <td class="tg-bsao">無</td>
    </tr>


  </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope any master would help me, thank you so much.

if possible we can chat in email. , leaengws@gmail.com, Telegram @bluequeenlea Many thanks!

### [Code edit planform for entire website][3] [embed code section to my site body][4] [Edit html in the section][5]

[1]: https://www.winlycarservises.com/car-list.html   [2]: https://www.winlycarservises.com/   [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwxPz.png   [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwxgx.png   [5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ld9pl.png

Comment: Please see my code below in answer section, thank you

Comment: What is the purpose of `.tg`? I don't see it marked as any classes?

Comment: <table data-role="table" data-mode="columntoggle" class="tg" id="tg-8fwH3" data-filter="true" data-input="#filterTable-input">

Comment: @カメロン thank you, I have deleted below